# NSMutableArray keeps returning null

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have declared a property NSMutableArray in the header file. Then I alloc, init it in the viewDidLoad method. But when I try to add an object to the array in a different method it keeps returning (null). Am I doing some obvious mistake? Please ask if you want to see some more code.

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myList;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.dataController = [[DataController alloc]init];

    self.myList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

[...]

```
NSDictionary *myObject = [self.dataController.objectList objectAtIndex:r];
[[cell textLabel]setText:[myObject objectForKey:@"title"]];

[self.myList addObject:myObject]; 

NSLog(@"myList %@",self.myList);
NSLog(@"myObject %@",myObject);
```

The output prints myObject but self.myList keeps returning (null). Appreciate all help!

**Edit:** Fixed, thank you for your answers!

Comment: Are you sure the view has already loaded by the time you try to access the list? Maybe you should be initializing those properties in `init` instead.

Comment: Where in the app is the code where you create myObject, add it to myList, and do the logs?

Comment: @KevinBallard The code in the third snippet is in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath so I guess the problem is that this method loads before viewDidLoad. However the log in viewDidLoad returns before the log in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath does. I tried to move the code from viewDidLoad to (id)init but never got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you are using this array. If you have to use this array before `viewDidLoad` is called, you can do it as,

```
NSDictionary *myObject = [self.dataController.objectList objectAtIndex:r];
[[cell textLabel]setText:[myObject objectForKey:@"title"]];

if (!self.myList)
    self.myList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//for the first time, this will initialize

[self.myList addObject:myObject];
```

Since you are using `[cell textLabel]` I am assuming that you are doing this in one of the table view delegates. In that case check if you are setting `self.myList = nil;` any where in the class.

Comment: it is used later than viewDidLoad -- else his code wouldnt print myObject. Or would it?

Comment: @Daij-Djan, Cant predict that from `myObject`. It could be that he is setting `dataController` from previous class itself and initialization part for `dataController` is not called while executing this. But I think you are correct due to the usage of `[cell textLabel]` which should be done in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`. That should have been called after `viewDidLoad`. But in any case he has to add more info to his question.

Comment: My thoughts were that he simply initialized `myObject` in `init` as well, but didn't realize / didn't mention it.

Comment: After a lot of debugging I finally found a little piece of code that set the list to nil. Now it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Emil, Glad to help. :) That's what I thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code i see  no error.
Set a breakpoint and look if the code where you init the array is called first.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that viewDidLoad hasn't been called yet when the NSLogs are execute.

To ensure that the array has been initialized, try putting the initialization in your init method.

Comment: I don't have any init method yet. When I try to add one it doesn't execute.